# ViewPager2 как обновлять данные во фрегментах

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

У меня есть фрагмент со строкой поиска и 2-мя табами с ViewPager2. Я хочу чтобы при вводе текста в строку поиска, этот текст передавался во фрагменты, и уже там выполнялся процесс получения и отображения данных, но не понимаю, как передать этот текст из хост фрагмента во фрагменты ViewPager'а. Подскажите, пожалуйста, знающие люди.

Comment: А какой стэк технологий используете? По идее, проще всего - реализацию паттерна "Наблюдатель" (RxJava или KotlinFlow или даже что-то самописное) через DI (Toothpick, Koin, Dagger2) во все фрагменты передать. Хотя можно и попробовать из конревого фрагмента дотянуться через FrgamentManager до внутренних фрагментов и вручную методы дёргать. Но это сложно и больно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сначала смотрел в сторону FragmentManager, но не хотелось привязываться к тегам, который FragmentStateAdapter самостоятельно задает. В итоге реализовал как вы и сказали, Dagger2 + RxJava, через общий репозиторий с subject'ом внутри.